# How to use Rails Url helper in Webpacker / React-rails in Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, react-rails, react-on-rails, webpacker

I am using [web-packer](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) with [react-rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) gem to build a online travel app. I am facing a problem of using Rails URL helper in my JSX view with server side rendering:

For example in my jsx view:

```html
#project/app/javascript/packs/app/components/front_end/SearchTripItemComp.erb
<%= link_to "Book Now!", search_trips_path, className: 'btn btn-book' %>
```

After running I've got this error:

[image]

What I can think of, as a work around, is to pass the search_trips_path as props to the Component from my Rails view or use Rails.application.routes.url_helpers directly but this is very inconvenient especially for those jsx views with many links.

I tried to look around web-packer docs but it seems that the gem did not support Rails view helper for erb loader.

Please help advice!

ps: I have erb webpacker loader configured correctly.

Comment: Yes, sorry, the only way is passing it as props. The helper is not available form your Javascript.

Answer (score 5):

Try this in your jsx view:

```js
#project/app/javascript/packs/app/components/front_end/SearchTripItemComp.erb
<%= ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to "Book Now!", Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.search_trips_path, className: 'btn btn-book' %>
```

Using:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.*_path
```

instead of

```
*_path
```

in your .erb files outside views works for url_helpers.

Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.search_trips_path

> If you need to generate URLs from your models or some other place, then ActionController::UrlFor is what you're looking for. Read on for an introduction. In general, this module should not be included on its own, as it is usually included by url_helpers (as in Rails.application.routes.url_helpers).
>
> [ActionDispatch::Routing::UrlFor](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html)

Similarly for link_to you can use:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to
```